# Saving data in android studio

Tags: javascript

I would like to understand how the following can be implemented:
i have html page
initially you get to the page with the choice of a group, after that you get to the schedule for the selected group
I am making an android app using webview
how can I make sure that the selected schedule for a specific group is saved and after re-entering the application, it does not get to the group selection, but already remains in the schedule

I don't fully understand where exactly I need to do this.
in the android studio itself, on the page with the choice of faculty, or on the page with the schedule itself